# Add a new row according to previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 index    Index_Date    A    B    C    D
 ===========================================
 1        2015-01-31    10   10   we   10
 2        2015-02-01     2    3   jk   22 and 23 and 24 
 3        2015-02-02    10   60   nm   280 and 284
 4        2015-02-03    10  100   oi   250
 5        2015-02-03    10  100   yh  Egyptian and Hittite
```

I want to reach

```
 index    Index_Date    A    B    C    D
 ===========================================
 1        2015-01-31    10   10   we  10
 2        2015-02-01     2    3   jk  22
 3        2015-02-01     2    3   jk  23
 4        2015-02-01     2    3   jk  24
 5        2015-02-02    10   60   nm  280
 6        2015-02-02    10   60   nm  284
 7        2015-02-03    10  100   oi  250
 8        2015-02-03    10  100   yh  Egyptian
 9        2015-02-03    10  100   yh  Hittite
```

Basically program need to find `and` statement and if find duplicated that row and then leave `before and` part (`22`) in the first `after and` part (`23`) in the duplicated row and the rest.

I start with this but I am not sure where I should go.

```
  for row in df:
        if df['D'].str.contains(' and ', case=True, na=False, regex=True):
```

Also I asked easlier version before. Again I am not sure it is too hard or too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to fine tune this and variations of this have been asked many times.

```
D = df.D.astype(str).str.split(' and ')
idx = df.index.repeat(D.str.len())
df.loc[idx].assign(D=np.concatenate(D).astype(int))

   Index_Date   A    B   C    D
0  2015-01-31  10   10  we   10
1  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   22
1  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   23
1  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   24
2  2015-02-02  10   60  nm  280
3  2015-02-03  10  100  oi  250
```

Comment: Thank you but I got "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe' "

Comment: @i2_ fixed it up

Comment: I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = '\s\s+')

Index_Date    A    B    C    D
2015-01-31    10   10   we  10
2015-02-01     2    3   jk  22 and 23 and 24 
2015-02-02    10   60   nm  280
2015-02-03    10  100   oi  250


df.set_index(['Index_Date', 'A', 'B', 'C']).D.str.split('and', expand = True)\
.stack().reset_index(4,drop = True).reset_index(name = 'D')

    Index_Date  A   B   C   D
0   2015-01-31  10  10  we  10
1   2015-02-01  2   3   jk  22
2   2015-02-01  2   3   jk  23
3   2015-02-01  2   3   jk  24
4   2015-02-02  10  60  nm  280
5   2015-02-03  10  100 oi  250
```

Comment: I see result has only 3 rows (with C == 'jk').

Comment: I don't get you?

Comment: I ran your code with dataframe as user provided and output is only 3 rows. My setup is as per my response, which I believe is identical to what user has.

Comment: I am not sure about your setup, I am getting the above data frame with the data frame posted by the OP.

Comment: My setup is transparent, care to share yours?

Comment: This the output of the df.to_dict() {'A': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 10, 3: 10},
 'B': {0: 10, 1: 3, 2: 60, 3: 100},
 'C': {0: 'we', 1: 'jk', 2: 'nm', 3: 'oi'},
 'D': {0: '10', 1: '22 and 23 and 24', 2: '280', 3: '250'},
 'Index_Date': {0: '2015-01-31',
  1: '2015-02-01',
  2: '2015-02-02',
  3: '2015-02-03'}}

Comment: The problem is with the data type of the data frame you have manually typed. Column D can't be int as the row with and will force it to be of type Object. Change all the numbers to string '10' and you will get the right output and in future please check your data before down voting other answers

Comment: Agreed, I upvoted yours. But I think it's important to note that your solution will only work if all types are `str`. Mine works either way.

Comment: Whenever you have a data that you need to split on a separator(be it and or comma or colon...), you are essentially looking at a string which can be split

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-01-31', 10, 10, 'we', 10],
                   ['2015-02-01', 2, 3, 'jk', '22 and 23 and 24'],
                   ['2015-02-02', 10, 60, 'nm', 280],
                   ['2015-02-03', 10, 100, 'oi', 250]],
                  columns=['Index_Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df.loc[df.D.astype(str).str.contains('and').fillna(False), 'D'] = df.D.str.split('and')

res = df.set_index(['Index_Date', 'A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
res = res.rename(columns={0: 'D'})
res.D = res.D.astype(int)
res = res[['Index_Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

#    Index_Date   A    B   C    D
# 0  2015-01-31  10   10  we   10
# 1  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   22
# 2  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   23
# 3  2015-02-01   2    3  jk   24
# 4  2015-02-02  10   60  nm  280
# 5  2015-02-03  10  100  oi  250
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser I got 
"     res.D = res.D.astype(int)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: and "  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3299, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3224, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3091, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 471, in astype
    **kwargs)
"

Comment: and 
"  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 521, in _astype
    values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 625, in astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 917, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/_libs/lib.c:16260)
"

Comment: and 
"  File "pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd", line 93, in util.set_value_at_unsafe (pandas/_libs/lib.c:70294)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '"

Comment: Unfortunately program works but it does not make the changes in my code. D column has some text variable.